# Parsing Json From Web Service With PHP

Tags: php, json, web-services, parsing

I'm new with json and web service. After using insert command, I do print_r($result) and got this data:

`Array ( [error_code] => 0 [error_desc] => [result] => Array ( [error_code] => 999 [error_desc] => Format input 'date' is wrong ) )`

I want to print the error_desc only which is show **Format input 'date' is wrong**.

I try to parsing it with PHP but I only got empty result. Here is my code:

```
if (is_array($result)) {
    if ($result['error_code'] =='999') {
      echo $result['error_desc'];
    }
  }
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer. I just know after print the error_code. Thanks.